# How to set Python virtual environment in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtual-environment

I have a .venv/ in my code folder.
It isn't the project root. Say it's projroot/tests/test1/.
VSCode Syntax Hilighter is flagging some of my `import`s.
This must be because it is using another .venv, and those packages don't exist in that one.
I've shebanged the file `#!.venv/bin/python` so I run it from the integrated terminal, but VSCode isn't smart enough to pick that up.
It isn't even smart enough to spot a `.venv/` folder in the pwd.
When I attempt to debug with VSCode, I can click the .venv being used on the bottom bar, and choose another one from a list, or even find one on the filesystem.
But I can't even SEE my `.venv/` folder (presumably it hides `.foo` folders).
I have to `CMD + SHIFT + g` and type in the path.
And it doesn't work.
It has no effect.
It doesn't fix hilighting, I can't debug, and I can't see what config file got modified.
If I DO try to modify my `launch.json` I don't know what to put in it.
There's a `settings.json` as well, but I guess I want `launch.json`.
I've heard that you can set `{launch/settings}.json` at different levels in your filesystem and VSCode will work back from the `pwd` until it finds one.

It's so frustrating. It's a beautiful code editor, but I always run into this .venv hell. Every time. And I can't find any clean reference.

Is there anyone out there that's used VSCode on macOS for Python dev that could put together a brief text that covers all the bases?  This must be a frustration point throughout the VSCode Python developer community.

Comment: `.venv` MUST be in the workspace root folder

Answer (score 0):

Hie firstly don't try to implement everything you are seeing others doing with vs code try to understand why there are doing that and try it if it meets your agenda

1st how to config python
The most efficient way is to download anaconda and install it

2rd what to do after installing
Make sure that the anaconda path and python path are recognised by the system
You can manually do so which l will cover if you want to know

3rd How to configure a code editor
Any code editor will detect anaconda as a python interpreter and you may start using it without frustrations